# Slow Berlin sparql benchmark queries in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying Berlin benchmark SPARQL queries in neo4j. I have created Neo4j graph from triples using http://michaelbloggs.blogspot.de/2013/05/importing-ttl-turtle-ontologies-in-neo4j.html

To summarize data loading, My graph has a following structure,

```
Subject   => Node
Predicate => Relationship
Object    => Node
```

If predicate is date, string, integer (primitive) then a property is created instead of relationship and stored in Node.

Now, I am trying following queries which are really slow in Noe4j,

```
Query 4: Feature with the highest ratio between price with that feature and price without that feature. 

    corresponding SPARQL query for this, 

            prefix bsbm: <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/vocabulary/>
            prefix bsbm-inst: <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/instances/>
            prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

            Select ?feature ((?sumF*(?countTotal-?countF))/(?countF*(?sumTotal-?sumF)) As ?priceRatio)
            {
              { Select (count(?price) As ?countTotal) (sum(xsd:float(str(?price))) As ?sumTotal)
                {
                  ?product a <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/instances/ProductType294> .
                  ?offer bsbm:product ?product ;
                         bsbm:price ?price .
                }
              }
              { Select ?feature (count(?price2) As ?countF) (sum(xsd:float(str(?price2))) As ?sumF)
                {
                  ?product2 a <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/instances/ProductType294> ;
                           bsbm:productFeature ?feature .
                  ?offer2 bsbm:product ?product2 ;
                         bsbm:price ?price2 .
                }
                Group By ?feature
              }
            }
           Order By desc(?priceRatio) ?feature
           Limit 100
 Cypher query I created for this,

    MATCH p1 = (offer1:Offer)-[r1:`product`]->(products1:ProductType294)
    MATCH p2 = (offer2:Offer)-[r2:`product`]->products2:ProductType294)-[:`productFeature`]->features
    return (sum( DISTINCT offer2.price) * ( count( DISTINCT offer1.price) - count( DISTINCT offer2.price)) /(count(DISTINCT offer2.price)*(sum( DISTINCT offer1.price) - sum(DISTINCT offer2.price)))) AS cnt,features.__URI__ AS frui
    ORDER BY cnt DESC,frui
```

This query is really slow, Please let me know whether I am formulating the query in wrong way.

```
Another query is Query 5: Show the most popular products of a specific product type for each country - by review count ,

      prefix bsbm: <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/vocabulary/>
      prefix bsbm-inst: <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/instances/>
      prefix rev: <http://purl.org/stuff/rev#>
      prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

      Select ?country ?product ?nrOfReviews ?avgPrice
      {
        { Select ?country (max(?nrOfReviews) As ?maxReviews)
          {
            { Select ?country ?product (count(?review) As ?nrOfReviews)
              {
                ?product a <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/instances/ProductType403> .
                ?review bsbm:reviewFor ?product ;
                        rev:reviewer ?reviewer .
                ?reviewer bsbm:country ?country .
              }
              Group By ?country ?product
            }
          }
          Group By ?country
        }
        { Select ?product (avg(xsd:float(str(?price))) As ?avgPrice)
          {
            ?product a <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/instances/ProductType403> .
            ?offer bsbm:product ?product .
            ?offer bsbm:price ?price .
          }
          Group By ?product
        }
        { Select ?country ?product (count(?review) As ?nrOfReviews)
          {
            ?product a <http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/instances/ProductType403> .
            ?review bsbm:reviewFor ?product .
            ?review rev:reviewer ?reviewer .
            ?reviewer bsbm:country ?country .
          }
          Group By ?country ?product
        }
        FILTER(?nrOfReviews=?maxReviews)
      }
      Order By desc(?nrOfReviews) ?country ?product

Cypher query I created for this is following,

    MATCH (products2:ProductType403)<-[:`reviewFor`]-(reviews:Review)-[:`reviewer`]->(rvrs)-[:`country`]->(countries)
    with count(reviews) AS reviewcount,products2.__URI__ AS pruis, countries.__URI__ AS cntrs
    MATCH (products1:ProductType403)<-[:`product`]-(offer:Offer)
    with AVG(offer.price) AS avgPrice, MAX(reviewcount) AS maxrevs, cntrs
    MATCH (products2:ProductType403)<-[:`reviewFor`]-(reviews:Review)-[:`reviewer`]->(rvrs)-[:`country`]->(countries)
    with avgPrice, maxrevs,countries, count(reviews) AS rvs, countries.__URI__ AS curis, products2.__URI__ AS puris
    where maxrevs=rvs
    RETURN curis,puris,rvs,avgPrice
```

Even this query is really slow. Am I formulating queries in correct way?

- I had 10M triples (berlin benchmark dataset)
- Every type predicate was converted into label.
- (For Query 4) what I'm trying to get is Feature with the highest ratio between price with
- that feature and price without that feature. Is this a right way to
  formulate query?
- (For Query 4) I get correct results for this query.
- If I don't compute the sum and count then query gets executed real fast.

Thanks in advance :) SPARQL queries and information can be found at : http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/bizer/berlinsparqlbenchmark/spec/BusinessIntelligenceUseCase/index.html#queries

Comment: Perhaps you can share your imported database, and add a model picture of the graph model you're using. Then we could try to help you. Just from the description, I don't really understand what you're doing. Except that your queries seem to be graph-global queries.

Answer (score 0):

These look like global graph queries to me?
What is the size of your dataset?

You create a cartesian product between the two paths?
Shouldn't those two paths somehow connected ?

Shouldn't there be a property `type` on a `ProductType` label? `(:ProductType {type:"294"})`
And if there was you'd have an index on :ProductType(type) and probably :Order(orderNo)

I don't really understand the calculation?

delta of count distinct prices times sum of distinct prices of offer 2
by
count of distinct prices of offer 2, times the delta of the sum of the two order prices?

```
MATCH (offer1:Offer)-[r1:`product`]->(products1:ProductType294)
MATCH (offer2:Offer)-[r2:`product`]->(products2:ProductType294)-[:`productFeature`]->features

RETURN (sum( DISTINCT offer2.price) * 
       ( count( DISTINCT offer1.price) - count( DISTINCT offer2.price)) 
       / (count(DISTINCT offer2.price)*
       (sum( DISTINCT offer1.price) - sum(DISTINCT offer2.price)))) 
       AS cnt,features.__URI__ AS frui
ORDER BY cnt DESC,frui
```